# Why in the given piece of code `fgetc()` function gave proper output whereas `fscanf()` failed to do so?

Tags: c, file-io, scanf, fgetc

The following piece of code worked :

```
 #include<stdio.h>
    void main()
    {
        FILE *ip, *op ;
        char ch ;
        ip = fopen ( "read.txt", "r" ) ;
        op = fopen ( "out.txt", "a" );
        while ( 1 )
        {
            ch = fgetc ( ip ) ;   //used for getting character from file read.txt
            if ( ch == EOF )
                break ;
            fprintf ( op, "%c", ch ) ;
        }
            fclose ( ip ) ;
            fclose ( op );
    }
```

But the following code was not giving required output as `fscanf()` was used :

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{
    FILE *fp, *op ;
    char ch ;
    fp = fopen ( "read.txt", "r" ) ;
    op = fopen ( "out.txt", "a" );
    while ( 1 )
    {
        ch = fscanf ( fp, "%c", &ch ) ;  //to read the characters from read.txt
        if ( ch == EOF )
            break ;
        fprintf ( op, "%c", ch ) ;
    }
        fclose ( fp ) ;
        fclose ( op );
}
```

I also don't understand how the variable `ch` was automatically taking up the next character.

Comment: Aside: `char ch ;` should be `int ch ;` which is the return type from `int fgetc(FILE *stream);`

Comment: It was working properly with `char ch ;` only

Comment: I was referring to the first program. It won't work if `char` is `unsigned`, which it can be on another compiler. The return value `EOF` (-1) will then be stored as `255` and the check will fail. Please take my advice. I don't beleive the first program failed when you defined `int ch;`

Comment: Sorry, I didn't check it the first time. It works. Thanks a lot.

Comment: If I want to do it with the help of `fscanf()`, how can I do it? @WeatherVane

Comment: char ch; while (fscanf(fp, "%c", &ch) == 1) { fprintf(op, "%c", ch); }

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you're assigning the result of `fscanf` to `ch`:

```
    ch = fscanf ( fp, "%c", &ch ) ;  //to read the characters from read.txt
//  ^^^^^---- here
    if ( ch == EOF )
        break ;
```

So first `fscanf` reads a character into `ch` (if there is one), and then it returns, and its return value is writte to `ch`, overwriting the character. The return value of `fscanf` is [*"Number of receiving arguments successfully assigned, or EOF if read failure occurs before the first receiving argument was assigned."*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) When when there's a character to read, you end up with `ch` being set to 1.

So:

```
if (fscanf ( fp, "%c", &ch ) != 1) {
    break;
```

or

```
if (fscanf ( fp, "%c", &ch ) == EOF) {
    break;
```

> I also don't understand how the variable `ch` was automatically taking up the next character.

Note the `&ch` part of `fscanf ( fp, "%c", &ch )`: That takes the address of the `ch` variable and passes that address into `fscanf`; `fscanf` receives a *pointer* to `ch`. `fscanf` writes data to the memory that pointer points to, which is why it ends up in `ch`.

Comment: In the first program, variable  `ch` automatically picked up the next character. I wanted to know if `fgetc()` automatically sets the pointer to next character.

Comment: @Sudeep: `fgetc` *returns* the character as its return value, so no, it doesn't set the character via pointer like `fscanf` does.

Comment: then how my program copied whole of the text file?

Comment: @Sudeep yes, `fgetc()` automatically moves the *file pointer* to the next character within the file, so if you keep calling `fgetc()` it will return each byte of the file one after another.